# What is the name of this theorem of lemma?

Tags: geometry

I looking for a name of this theorem or lemma,

"In given triangle *ABC*, the angle bisector of angle *BAC* meets with a circumcenter at middle point of arc *BC*".

I can't find this theorem or lemma's name in English.

Comment: You presumably meant "circumcircle, not "circumcenter". I doubt that this result has a standard name because it's an immediate corollary of the fact that the measure of an angle inscribed in a circle is half the measure of the arc it subtends.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem that equal angles at the circumference of a circle stand on equal arcs is Euclid III,26. Hence the bisector of $\angle BAC$ bisects arc $BC$. It will pass through the circumcenter, however, only if $AB=AC$, since then it will be the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ (see Euclid III,1 Porism; VI,3).